# Изменение цвета кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы выделенный текст (указан в !!** ... **!!) отрабатывался автоматически, а не по нажатию на кнопку?

```
  <script>
        let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input__file');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs, function (input) {
          let label = input.nextElementSibling,
            labelVal = label.querySelector('.input__file-button-text').innerText;
      
          input.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
            let countFiles = '';
            if (this.files && this.files.length >= 1)
              countFiles = this.files.length;
      
            if (countFiles)
              {label.querySelector('.input__file-button-text').innerText = 'Выбрано файлов: ' + countFiles;



           !!**var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
           btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
           this.classList.add("active");});**!!
           
     

 }
        else
          label.querySelector('.input__file-button-text').innerText = labelVal;
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну, тут всё предельно просто: вы просто присвоение класса с цветом из слушателя событий уберите. Получится как-то так.

```
btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.classList.add("active");
```

Но надо понимать, что если этого элемента нет перед местом выполнения скрипта, то ничего не произойдёт и вы увидите в консоли ошибку.

Тут есть несколько путей решения:

1. Просто проверьте наличие элемента перед выполнением скрипта.
2. Поместите скрипт в конец страницы
3. Поместите скрипт куда хотите, но дождитесь подгрузки страницы:

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) =>{

btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.classList.add("active");

});
```

Или

```
window.onload = function(){

btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.classList.add("active");

};
```

[Сайт с документацией](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)